# Adding text to circle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I drew a circle and wanted to add text `$T_1$` inside it:

```
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.3] {$T_1$};
```

Why does this not work, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use a node to add the label

```
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.3] node {$T_1$};
```

or use a `\node` with `circle` shape:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-2,-2) grid (3,3);
\draw (0,0) circle [radius=0.3] node {$T_1$};
\node[draw,circle,minimum size=1cm,inner sep=0pt] at (2,0) {$T_1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]